# Выборка по двум условиям из связнной таблицы

Tags: запрос, связывание-данных, выборка, mysql

Всем привет. Мучаюсь второй день.

Предположим, есть таблица пользователей с полями `id` и `name` (ид - уникальный), и есть связанная таблица, связывающая этих пользователей с группами. В этой таблице поля `user_id` и `group_id`. Нужно одним запросом получить пользователей, находящихся одновременно и в группе 6, и в группе 12.

Вроде звучит просто, но что-то ничего не получается. :( Смог только получить всех пользователей, которые находятся в группе 6, и всех, кто в группе 12, а потом фильтровать лишних уже кодом, но в виду очень большого количества данных - выборка занимает 7 секунд, что крайне неприлично долго... Буду благодарен за любые идеи...

Comment: @Etki будьте добры, переведите комментарий в ответ.
@HukpoFuJl если один из ответов является верным, пожалуйста, не поленитесь отметить данный ответ как верный.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN relations AS r1 ON r1.user_id = u.id AND r1.group_id = 6
INNER JOIN relations AS r2 ON r2.user_id = u.id AND r2.group_id = 12
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас опробую...

Comment: Странно, но в моем случае находит 0 записей =((

Comment: Хотя, если смоделировать ситуацию, что я описал тут - то всё работает... Ок, от этого буду и плясать, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так

```
where group_id in(6,12)
```